# Automatic cell math google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a stats tracker for a game using a Google spreadsheet and as you can see in the linked image below, D2 is subtracted from D3 to give F3 a value. The E and G columns have the same relation.

My issue is, while the formula is simple (i.e. in F3 type, =d3-d2 , to get a value), typing this formula 100 times altogether is a bit mundane.

Is there anyway that I can have this done automatically? I have more features I'd like to add, but I am holding off because of this issue.

Hopefully this link works, I don't have enough rep to post an image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1uuK.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to type the formula for each cell, you can just select the cell, copy it and paste it on the cell below. The cells referenced are relative to their position so they will change accordingly.

For example in your case, if you select and copy cell F3 and paste it on cell F4 you will see that the pasted formula will actually be =D4-D3

Answer (score 0):

Just left-click in the bottom right-hand corner of the formula you want to copy (or even number sequence), and drag it down or across however many cells you like.  The program will recognize the pattern and continue it accordingly.